# Ubuntu 14.04 Graphics Driver Confusion

Tags: 14.04, ati

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a system which has an ATI 5450 series graphics card.

I was able to use the full screen resolutions right out of the box, but I noticed that the performance is poor relative to my experience on Windows.  Screens which fade in and out do so slowly, and watching HD films results in a 'blocking' of fast moving video.

I decided to visit the AMD page and I followed their [instructions](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx#) to install the Catalyst Control Centre.

Having done that I noticed no significant improvement in video performance.  I can run the Catalyst Control Centre, and I've played with some of the settings in there, all to no avail.

When I go to Settings->Details->Overview the Graphics information is listed as "VESA: 103".  This leads me to suspect that perhaps the ATI proprietary graphics drivers are not being used, even though I installed them as per the instructions and catalyst control centre is working.  I tried to google VESA: 103 but I was not able to find any information which would help me understand what's going on.

Is anyone able to help me come to an understanding about which drivers Ubuntu is using to control my graphics card?